# NPM Bootstrap Carousel Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Using the NPM build of Bootstrap (with Gulp) for a WordPress theme and I'm not sure entirely what could be going wrong. New to Bootstrap, not new to WordPress or Gulp (previously used Foundation).

Here's how I include the Bootstrap files,

```
// Set path to Bootstrap files
const BOOTSTRAP = 'node_modules/bootstrap';

// Select Bootstrap components, remove components project will not use
const SOURCE = {
    scripts: [

        // Bootstrap core 
        BOOTSTRAP + '/dist/js/bootstrap.js',

        // Pick the components you need in your project
        BOOTSTRAP + '/js/dist/carousel.js',

        // Place custom JS here, files will be concatenated
        'assets/scripts/js/**/*.js'
        ],

    // SCSS files will be concatenated
    styles: ['assets/styles/scss/**/*.scss'],
};
```

My carousel markup,

```
<?php
    $testimonial_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'testimonial',
    );
    $testimonial_query =  new WP_Query( $testimonial_args );
?>
<div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
<?php
    $testimonial_integer = 0;
    if ( $testimonial_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $testimonial_query->have_posts() ) : $testimonial_query->the_post(); $testimonial_integer++;?>
        <div class="carousel-item <?php if ( 1 === $testimonial_integer ) { echo 'active'; } ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php echo get_field('position'); ?>
            <?php echo get_field('city_state'); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    ?>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Nothing wild going on here, yet I'm thrown this console error,

```
scripts.js?ver=5.8.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at _inherits (scripts.js?ver=5.8.3:1:6106)
    at scripts.js?ver=5.8.3:1:77341
    at scripts.js?ver=5.8.3:1:84943
    at scripts.js?ver=5.8.3:1:76256
    at scripts.js?ver=5.8.3:1:76312
```

That error only comes up when I include the carousel JS file. However, it doesn't look like the error's actually in that JS file.

I read another answer that claimed a fix was a newer version of Bootstrap but w/ NPM I ought to have the latest, I've even run `npm update`

I feel like I'm not including some other JS file I need but...??

Answer (score 0):

Was using 5.1.3 but downgraded to 4.6.1 (which has the util.js file, 5.1.3 doesn't for some reason??). Included the util.js file before including carousel and it worked like a charm!